# Running a docker command in a user-service

Tags: systemd, docker, docker-compose

I am migrating some apps on my home service to docker. There are several background jobs, running as user-service, using these apps.

But I receive the following error

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dprod%22%3Atrue%7D%7D&limit=0": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I have already added the current user to the docker group. It is possible to run the commands manually. But it doesn't work as user-service. After changing

`chmod 666 docker.sock`

it works also for the user-service.

But I'd like to know which specific user need the permission for docker in this case?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A reboot fixed this :-) :-) :-) :-)